# How would you apologise for not inviting someone to an event?

Tags: translation, verbs

In English I would say something along the line of 'Sorry! I forgot to invite you to the party'. This would be in conversation to a friend. How would this translate to Japanese?

Edit (First post to this site sorry!): My first ideas would be along the line of すみません、私は招待しにわすれました。Through looking in my 'Genki' textbook, this verb conjugation is mainly used for movement, not for the purpose I am using it for. Please could someone explain to me - if it is incorrect - why it is so?

Answer (score -3):

As with many translations in Japanese there are numerous ways to do this:

Written way with "you" specified ( but we don't speak this way ):

> パーティーにあなたを招待していないのが残念です

Leaving off "You":

> パーティーに招待していないのが残念です

Here, we have used 残念 ( zan nen - too bad or unfortunate )

In the follow we use ごめん なさい ( gomen nasai which is more like "sorry" ):

> パーティーに招待するのを忘れたのがごめんなさい

Please forgive me because I forgot to invite (you) to the party

> パーティーに招待するのを忘れたので許してください

Very informal among friends ( forgot to invite thing is no good ):

> 招待するのを忘れたのは良くない

Comment: なんで, 説明なしにこれに反対票を投じた人はばかだ

Comment: The majority of these sentences are either unnatural or just entirely incorrect...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Please elaborate if you are able...

Comment: 1. 「パーティーに招待してないのが残念です」 sounds either odd (as if the subject is some third party, not you), or passive aggressive at best. 2. The grammar 「〜のがごめんなさい」 is never used. 3. 「忘れたので許してください」 is weird because it’s providing the fact that you forgot as the *reason* they should forgive you, not as what they should forgiving you *for*. 4. 「〇〇のは良くない」 is simply not a way to apologize or repent for 〇〇. HTH.